# Why is $D$ a $2$-form and $E$ a $1$-form?

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry

Usually in electrostatics we start by introducing the vector field $\mathbf{E}$ representing the electric field due to some charge distribution. Later when we study fields in materials we consider the electric displacement field $\mathbf{D}=\epsilon_0 \mathbf{E}+\mathbf{P}$ being $\mathbf{P}$ the polarization density.

When we want to generalize things to differential forms, $\mathbf{E}$ becomes a $1$-form and $\mathbf{D}$ becomes a $2$-form. Similarly occurs with $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{H}$.

Why is that? Why should we make those decisions when modeling [electromagnetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_the_electromagnetic_field) with differential forms?

Comment: Can you provide a specific reference to the identification of $E$ and $D$ with 1- and 2- forms?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, here is one reference doing this identifications http://125.71.228.222/wlxt/ncourse/dccydcb/web/condition/9.pdf. Compared to the usual definitions of $E$ and $D$ I didn't understand correctly what's the intuition on this.

Answer (score 1):

As Flanders says forms are what we integrate. Since the (surface) integral of D over a surface is the enclosed charge hence D must be a 2-form. Similarly, the work of taking a unit charge along a path is the contour integral of E, then the latter must be a 1-form. They just cannot be anything else.

Comment: To add to user31748's answer, when we integrate the form over a manifold, we are essentially taking a pairing between the differential form and the fundamental homology class of the manifold, providing it is orientable.